# How to set a variable to a field value retrieved in a query

Tags: vba, ms-access

Updated 3/14/19 to include code for setting variable and Run-time error is '2427' 'You entered an expression that has no value.' on setting outCome1 variable

```
Private Sub Report Open(Cancel As Integer)    
    Dim outCome1 As String  
  ' Set public variable to true to indicate that the report    
  ' is in the Open event  
    bInReportOpenEvent = True  
    MsgBox (bInReportOpenEvent)  
  ' Open Appt Query Dialog  
    DoCmd.OpenForm "craid CMM Client Report Dialog", , , , , acDialog  
    Cancel Report if User Clicked the Cancel Button  
    If IsLoaded("craid CMM Client Report Dialog") = False Then Cancel = True
    outCome1 = (Reports("CMM Client Status Report").Controls("googleoutcome").Value)    
    MsgBox (outCome1)  

  ' Set public variable to false to indicate that the  
  ' Open event is completed  
  '  bInReportOpenEvent = False  
End Sub
```

Also, I notice when I run that bInReportOpenEvent does not stay True when in Dialog Form and so it doesn't appear to be public even though I have run Sub Report Open with Public and it still doesn't stay True when in Dialog Form.

---

I am new, but have been struggling quite a bit with trying to set a variable to a field value retrieved in a query, so thought I would see if I can get some relief.

I am writing an Access Report that uses a Dialog Form to prompt user for which record in database to display on Report.

I use a query as the Record Source for the report. One of the fields I retrieve with the query is `googleoutcome`. I want to set a variable to the value of `googleoutcome`, so I can then do a test on it and display the result on my report.

I have tried:

```
Dim outCome1 As String  
outCome1=Me!googleoutcome
```

```
Dim outCome1 As String  
outCome1=[googleoutcome]
```

```
Dim outCome1 As String  
outCome1=Me.googleoutcome
```

I am receiving the error:

> error '2427; You entered an expression that has no value.

Any help is appreciated.

Laura

Comment: Assuming `Me` has a `Fields` collection, `Me.Fields("googleoutcome").Value` should work, and `Me!googleoutcome` would be equivalent. Where is that code written in?

Comment: The code is written in the Report Open event, right after I open the Dialog Form. Laura

Comment: In that case it is probably helpful to [edit] the post to include the code that's showing the form, since that's where the field is, right? `theForm.Fields("googleoutcome").Value` should be it.

Comment: The field is in my report.

Answer (score 1):

In VBA, the [`Me`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/me-keyword) keyword refers to an instance of the class in which the current code is executing. For example, in MS Access, if you use `Me` within a **Form Module**, it will return an instance of the active **Form**; if you use it within a **Report Module**, it will return an instance of the active **Report**.

Therefore, your use of `Me` in the `On Open` event handler for the Report is returning an instance of the *Report* which is being opened, not the *Form* you have opened.

Instead, you could reference the value of the form control by traversing the object model in the following way:

```
Forms("YourFormName").Controls("YourControlName").Value
```

Comment: I have changed the above suggestion to:

    Reports("YourReportName").Controls("YourControlName).Value  

and am getting error:

Run-time error '2427': You entered an expression that has no value.

Comment: Why did you change it?

Comment: Because the field is in my report, not in my form. When I use suggestion, I get error:

Run-time error '94': Invalid use of Null

Comment: @user3435209 that's a good sign, it means the field value is being accessed, but the value is apparently `Null`; try declaring `outcome1 As Variant` instead of `As String`

Comment: I am using suggestion Forms("YourFormName").Controls("YourControlName") and changed variable declaration outcome1 as Variant. No error! I added
MsgBox (outcome1) and I get error:
Run-time error '94': Invalid use of Null.
My text box control on report has:
    Name                googleoutcome
    Control Source googleoutcome

and prints on Report as 1. Maybe I have text box values wrong?